# PHP login mysqli problems

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm kind of new in PHP and MySQL. When I test this code with a test user, it always allows the credentials. So it's not properly checking if the data is in the database or not, but I can't seem to see what's wrong.

What is the right way to code this?

```
//check connection to database
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Perform queries
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username='$name' AND password='$password'");
echo mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1){
    session_start();
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id_user'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $data['password'];
    echo "Proses Login";
    print "<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; URL=admin/index.php'</meta></head></html>";
}
else {
    echo "Login Denied";
    print "<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; URL=admin/index2.php'</meta></head></html>";
}
```

Comment: You need to `include('');` your sql connection file and also mention your `MYSQLI` Connection in your query as : `mysqli_query($con,"Your Query Here");`

Comment: On side note(s) This is likely a security issue `"SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username='$name' AND password='$password'"` from two standpoints a) You should be using bind parameters b) you are probably storing a plaintext password

Comment: And yes Ofcourse the better way is to use prepared statements as : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: This code is full of problems. Please read about SQL injection and PHP session management. Look up example PHP login forms online.

Comment: Also, I would throw `session_start();` at the very top of the page before everything, there is no real reason to only include it in a conditional.

Comment: @Rasclatt : Yes but may be if he is encoding the password somewhere above in his code??? Or May be his not that smart..! :D

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Well, being so incomplete, it's all just guessing a this point.

Comment: @Rasclatt : Yup I got it...! :D You know I was just saying..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Also, if the password was stored as a hash using `password_hash()` (or compatible) the OP would have only checked for username from the database, then used `password_verify()` to verify the password returned by the query. Anyway, like you say it's hard to guess, but there are telltale signs. :D

Comment: imo, Don't bother checking `num_rows` - just fetch the data. If it is `!empty` then process it - otherwise report the error. The only time you check 'affected_rows' is for update, insert or delete. Well - insert or delete anyway.

Answer (score -3):

```
$con = "It must have your database connection.(Put yours credentials here)" . 

$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username='$name' AND password='$password'");
```

Then change  `echo mysqli_num_rows($sql)` to  below line:

```
$result= mysqli_num_rows($con,$sql);
```

Then,

```
if($result == 1){
Your code goes on.....
}
```

Comment: Well...Buddy you are doing it too much wrong..! :D Sorry no offence but -1 for that..

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Thats kool Dude.Cheers ;)

Comment: @Sumari Kalyan : You don't need to mention your `$con` in `mysqli_num_rows` just only in your `mysqli_query`

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at this link for better understanding : http://codular.com/php-mysqli